# Part not behaving the way I expect it to

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, syntax, assignment

```
p = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};
p[[All, 3]][[1 ;; 2]] = {1, 1};
p
```

I want to replace the first two elements of the third column of a 3x3 identity matrix.

The above code does not work. I get a depth-error message.

> Set::partd: Part specification is longer than depth of object

I am confused because the following code is functional.

```
p[[All, 3]][[1 ;; 2]]
```

Comment: try `p[[1 ;; 2, 3]] = {1, 1}`?

Comment: @kglr, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 14):

The way `Set` works in setting parts of an expression is this:

```
symb[[..<part specification>..]] = values;
```

The component `symb` must be a ***symbol*** (i.e. with head [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html)).

In the OP's code,

```
p[[All,3]][[1;;2]] = {1,1};
```

The `symb` component is `p[[All,3]]`, which is not a symbol.

Fix as @kglr suggests,

```
p[[1 ;; 2, 3]] = {1, 1};
```

As for evaluating `p[[All,3]][[1;;2]]`, you can see the procedure in `Trace[p[[All, 3]][[1 ;; 2]]]`.  First `p[[All, 3]]` is evaluated.  The expression then becomes

```
{0, 0, 0}[[1 ;; 2]]
```

(If `p` is meant to be the identity matrix, then the third row is wrong.)

Comment: Yeah, got, thank you!!!:)

Comment: @吴剑涛 You're welcome. :)

Comment: @吴剑涛 If this fully answers your question in a satisfactory way it is appropriate for you to [Accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

```
p = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};

f = MapAt[1 &, {1 ;; 2, 3}];

f @ p
```

{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}

If we want to change `p` inline we can use `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

```
p //= f;

p
```

{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
p = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};

SubsetMap[{1, 1} &, p, {{1, 3}, {2, 3}}]

(*{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}*)
```