# How to use loops with indexed objects?

Tags: variable-definitions

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to work with `Do` for a set of indexed objects in order to avoid doing the same action repeatedly. For example, I create the following lists:

```
dog[1] = {{1, 1}, {5, 7}, {3, 10}}; 
dog[2] = {{7, 2}, {11, 8}, {4, 3}};
dog[3] = {{1, 7}, {1, 5}, {9, 3}};
```

And I want to change the value of the second columns on each of these 10 times. My approach to the problem:

`Do[Part[dog[i], All, 2] = 10*Part[Perro[i], All, 2], {i, 3}]`

But it returns me the error: `dog[i] in the part assignment is not a symbol.` How can this be fixed? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: please have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/how-to-set-parts-of-indexed-lists), you may want to change your initialization to `dog = ConstantArray[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}, 3]`.

Comment: @happyfish Thanks for your advice, but my example was wrong. I'm now working with lists that have the same number in their columns, I wrote it that way just to give and example that's why I edited it.

Comment: Is `dog` a function? It looks to me that you want `dog` to be a vector. To access vector components, you need double square brackets `[[]]`. If it's a function, I don't think you can assign to a part of it.

Comment: Related: [(72624)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72624/121), [(148387)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148387/121)

Comment: You would be better using an Association if you have Mathematica 10 or later, you wouldn't have any problem doing what you want with it.

Comment: @faysou Agreed; I just posted an answer below with that.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Felix. You were right, I had to use double square brackets, I felt so dumb when I tried it after approaching in several different ways without success. And also thanks to everyone of you who helped.

Answer (score 4):

I do the kind of thing you describe quite frequently and to do it I use what I call the `Module` trick. `Part` needs a variable as its 1st argument when it is used on the lefthand side of an assignment. The idea is use a local variable in a module. Here is an example using your data.

```
dog[1] = {{1, 1}, {5, 7}, {3, 10}};
dog[2] = {{7, 2}, {11, 8}, {4, 3}};
dog[3] = {{1, 7}, {1, 5}, {9, 3}};

Array[dog, 3]
```

> `{{{1, 1}, {5, 7}, {3, 10}}, 
>   {{7, 2}, {11, 8}, {4, 3}}, 
>   {{1, 7}, {1, 5}, {9, 3}}}`

```
Do[dog[i] = Module[{d = dog[i]}, d[[All, 2]] = 10 d[[All, 2]]; d], {i, 3}]
```

Then

```
Array[dog, 3]
```

> `{{{1, 10}, {5, 70}, {3, 100}}, 
>   {{7, 20}, {11, 80}, {4, 30}}, 
>   {{1, 70}, {1, 50}, {9, 30}}}`

Answer (score 3):

Since version 10 [Associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) provide a new approach:

```
dog = <||>;

dog[1] = {{1, 1}, {5, 7}, {3, 10}};
dog[2] = {{7, 2}, {11, 8}, {4, 3}};
dog[3] = {{1, 7}, {1, 5}, {9, 3}};

Do[dog[[i, All, 2]] *= 10 i, {i, 3}]

dog
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {{1, 10}, {5, 70}, {3, 100}},
>   2 -> {{7, 40}, {11, 160}, {4, 60}},
>   3 -> {{1, 210}, {1, 150}, {9, 90}}|>
> ```

This works also with arbitrary key names like `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, which can be addressed with either the integer position or the key name itself: `dog[[1, All, 2]]` or `dog[["a", All, 2]]`.