# Combining Multiple Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, variable, indexed-variable

Let's say I have 4 lists:

```
list1 = {a,b,c,d};
list2 = {e,f,g,h};
list3 = {i,j,k,l};
list4 = {m,n,o,p};
```

I can combine them using Join

```
Join[list1, list2, list3, list4]
```

My question is if there's another way to do this in such a way that I could reuse the code for 8 or 10 (or even 100) lists without having to type out each name (list1, list2. etc) separately?  Thanks.

Comment: Join @@ Table[ToExpression["list" <> ToString@i], {i, 1, 4}]

Comment: Thank you.  That works.

Answer (score 5):

Using [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html):

```
list[1] = {a, b, c, d};
list[2] = {e, f, g, h};
list[3] = {i, j, k, l};
list[4] = {m, n, o, p};

Array[list, 4, 1, Join]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p}
> ```

Joining lists in a different order:

```
list /@ {2, 1, 4, 3} // Catenate
```

> ```
> {e, f, g, h, a, b, c, d, m, n, o, p, i, j, k, l}
> ```

For versions 10 and later using [Associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) can have [advantages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152215/121).

```
Clear[list]

list = <||>;
list[1] = {a, b, c, d};
list[2] = {e, f, g, h};
list[3] = {i, j, k, l};
list[4] = {m, n, o, p};

Catenate[list]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p}
> ```

Related examples:

- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [Constructing variable names from a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9974/121)

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, the answer by @Mr.Wizard is the way to create and manipulate many lists. **But**, that doesn't answer OP's question if one can't create the lists oneself and need to deal with lists already created with complicated names.

Using [`Names`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html) gives a list of the names of symbols that match the string or pattern,

```
Names["list*"]
(* {"list1", "list2", "list3", "list4"} *)
```

Therefore adding [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) and [`Catenate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html)

```
Catenate[ToExpression /@ Names["list*"]]

(* {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p} *)
```

So, this answer your question, but ultimately the advisable implementation is the one by  @Mr.Wizard.