# Modify Dynamic value within EventHandler

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, eventhandler

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe program using a 3x3 board list running inside of a `DynamicModule` with a separate window displaying the current value and accepting clicks from the user. For now I'm just trying to use `EventHandler` to set any empty boxes to `X`'s when clicked.

When I click on a box, I get the error

> Part::pkspec1: The expression x cannot be used as a part specification.

Is this an issue with assigning a new value for board inside of the `EventHandler`?

How else should I structure this?

```
createBox[elem_] := Show[
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[]}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[.02], FrameTicks -> None],
  Graphics@Text[Style[elem, FontSize -> 100], {.5, .5}],
  ImageSize -> 150
  ]  

DynamicModule[{board = Table[Table[" ", 3], 3]},
  CreateWindow[
   DocumentNotebook[
    (*Displaying grid*)
    Dynamic@Grid[
      Table[Table[
        EventHandler[
         createBox[board[[y]][[x]]]
         , {"MouseClicked" :> (
            If[board[[y]][[x]] == " ", board[[y]][[x]] = "X";];
            )}]
        , {x, 3}], {y, 3}],
      Spacings -> {0, 0}]
    ],
   WindowElements -> {}, WindowTitle -> "Tic Tac Toe", 
   WindowSize -> All, Editable -> False, Selectable -> False, 
   ShowCellBracket -> False, WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox"}];
  ];
```

Comment: In the "Applications" section of [`Toggler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Toggler.html) there's an example of one way to use it for a Tic-Tac-Toe game (might be a possible starting point).

Comment: @Anne I'm not quite sure if this is what I'm looking for as I'm also aiming so have an AI player later on which won't be able to click the squares (I'd also prefer to have my own function to make moves rather than toggling a variable, my code is just testing click functionality)

Comment: Yeah, that makes total sense (wasn't expecting it to fit exactly, just thought I'd throw it out there just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main issues:

- set part

  `board[[y]][[x]] = val` will not work, you need `board[[y, x]] = "X"`

  See: [Part not behaving the way I expect it to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148387/5478)
- `x` and `y` can't get inside `:>`

  `RuleDelayed` holds and so after `Table` is done you will have `board[[y, x]]` in each item, instead of expected e.g. `board[[2,1]]` etc.

  The way to go is to use `With[{i=i},...` idiom, see: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478)
- `DynamicModule` is 'a scoped rectangle in your screen'

  So instead of `DynamicModule[.. CreateWindow..` it should rather be `CreateWindow[.. DynamicModule..`

  See e.g. [IntroductionToDynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html)

### Secondary issues

- you don't need `Dynamic` around `Grid`, only content of `board` changes so you can put it inside `createBox[Dynamic[...]]`
- it is better to use `===` instead of `==` to compare non numerical values
- `Show[Graphics...]` can be combined in one `Graphics[...]`
- Unless you need it we can replace `CreateWindow[NotebookDocument` with `CreateDocument` (*omg, I just realized the origin of this function name, thanks*)
- but your notebook's options suggest it may be enough to use `CreateDialog`
- you can combine nested `Table` into one

### Summing up:

```
createBox[elem_] := Graphics[
  { { White, Rectangle[] }
  , Text[Style[elem, FontSize -> 100], {.5, .5}]
  }
, ImageSize -> 150
, Frame -> True
, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.02]
, FrameTicks -> None
];

CreateDialog[
  DynamicModule[
    {board = ConstantArray[" ", {3, 3}]}
  , Grid[
      Table[ With[{x = x, y = y}
      , EventHandler[
          createBox[ Dynamic @ board[[y, x]]]
        , {"MouseClicked" :> If[board[[y, x]] === " ", board[[y, x]] = "X"]
          }
        ]]
      , {x, 3}, {y, 3}
      ]
    , Spacings -> {0, 0}
    ]
  ]
, WindowTitle -> "Tic Tac Toe"
, WindowSize -> All
];
```

[image]