# Understanding this Set error

Tags: warning-messages

Given the toy vector:

```
elettrone={{1.5, 1.5, 0.064, 1.4289, -2.0901, 790.138},{1.5, 1.5, 0.064, 1.4289, -2.0901, 790.138},{1.5, 1.5, 0.064, 1.4289, -2.0901, 790.138}}
```

I try to change the first three elements as follows:

```
elettrone[[All, 1]][[1]] -= 
  dx*Sin[elettrone[[All, 4]][[1]]]*Cos[elettrone[[All, 5]][[1]]];
elettrone[[All, 2]][[1]] -= 
  dx*Sin[elettrone[[All, 4]][[1]]]*Sin[elettrone[[All, 5]][[1]]];
elettrone[[All, 3]][[1]] -= dx*Cos[elettrone[[All, 4]][[1]]];
```

with `dx=0.0001`. I get the error:

> > Set::partd: Part specification elettrone[[All,1,n]] is longer than
> >     depth of object.
> >
> > Set::partd: Part specification elettrone[[All,2,n]]
> >     is longer than depth of object.
> >
> > Set::partd: Part specification
> >     elettrone[[All,3,n]] is longer than depth of object.

How can this error appear I am not writing `elettrone[[All,1,n]]`!

I am using version 11.3 for windows

Comment: Not sure the exact source but it is probably related to the fact that you can't do `a[[All, 1]][[2]] = ...` you need to do `a[[2, 1]] = ...`. See: [Part not behaving the way I expect it to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148387/5478)

Comment: If all else fails, you could consider using `ReplacePart[]`...

Comment: After some inspection, we can clearly see that the toy code is only concerned with the very first sublist of `elettrone`.

Comment: By the way, I do not get `n` in version 10.2, I get 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing that your code seems to want to do can be done by the following:

```
With[{dx = 0.0001}, 
 MapAt[
   {#1 - dx Sin[#4] Cos[#5], #2 - dx Sin[#4] Sin[#5], #3 - dx Cos[#4], #4, #5} & @@ # &,
   elettrone, {1}
 ]
]
```

or, to extend the same pattern to every sublist

```
{#1 - dx Sin[#4] Cos[#5], #2 - dx Sin[#4] Sin[#5], #3 - dx Cos[#4], #4, #5} & @@@ elettrone
```