# Part Assignment of variables with argument

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

I do not really understand why this:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
a[[1]] = 3;
a
```

> {3,2,3}

works as desired, but this does not:

```
b[1] = {1, 2, 3};
b[1][[1]] = 3;
b[1]
```

> Set::setps: b[1] in the part assignment is not a symbol.

Can I not treat variables with arguments like 'normal' variables?

Comment: closely related: [148387](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148387/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html):

```
ClearAll[b]
b[1] = {1, 2, 3};
b[1] = ReplacePart[ b[1], 1 -> 3];
b[1]
```

> {3, 2, 3}

Alternatively, [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
ClearAll[b]
b[1] = {1, 2, 3};
b[1] = MapAt[3 &, b[1], {1}];
b[1]
```

> {3, 2, 3}

Comment: Interesting thank you. What would I do If I wanted to set a column in a two Dimensional array? Like this: `a = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}]
a[[;; , 3]] = ConstantArray[2, 10];
a`

Comment: @MrPuh, the code in your comment works as expected.

Comment: yeah, I mean in the sense of the question, I would want something like this now: `a[1] = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}] a[1][[;; , 3]] = ConstantArray[2, 10]; a[1]`

Comment: @MrPuh, you can do `ClearAll[a];a[1] = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}] ;a[1]=MapAt[ 2&,a[1], {All,3}];a[1]` or `ClearAll[a];a[1] = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}] ;
a[1]=ReplacePart[ a[1], {_,3}->2];a[1]`

Comment: ... you can also use `SubsetMap`: `ClearAll[a];a[1] = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}] ;
a[1]=SubsetMap[ConstantArray[2,10]&,a[1], {All,3}];a[1]`