# Changing Lists in Associations

Tags: associations

On Mathematica 12.2 the code

```
x = <||>;
AssociateTo[x, "foo" -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
x["foo"][[1]] += {0, 1}
```

raises the error

Set::setps: x[foo] in the part assignment is not a symbol.

whereas

```
x["foo"][[1]]
```

returns {1,2} just fine.

Should the increment work?

Comment: Closing as this is in the docs. Read ref/message/General/setps in the documentation center. It says _Part assignments are implemented only for parts of the value of a symbol._ . The `x["foo"][[1]]` is not a symbol so you cannot set it with `=`.

Comment: closely related: [Part not behaving the way I expect it to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148387/5478)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* access the subparts of the association via `x["foo"][[1]]`, but you could also access it as `x[["foo", 1]]`.  Knowing that, your increment statement should be written

```
In[73]:= x[["foo", 1]] += {0, 1}

Out[73]= {1, 3}
```